# Is it possible to style Mat-Checkbox to show an X instead of checkmark?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Trying to implement a functionality using Angular Material `<mat-checkbox>` where if the user clicks on a `Yes` Button, it shows a checkmark. If the user clicks `No` Button, it would show an X. I find Angular Material official guide a little vague on this I guess.

I have tried adding new 'X' svg as content inside mat-checkbox-background class but only works with encapsulation.
I can not add in global as well because I have used `<mat-checkbox>` in other components too.I only want it to apply to one component.

```
 .mat-checkbox-background{
     content: url(/assets/icons/cancel_checkbox.svg) !important;
  }
```

Please give some suggestions
Thanks!

Note: do not want to use encapsulation as it affects Other styles.

Comment: Did you try this class .mat-checkbox  .mat-checkbox-background {}?

Comment: Is it angularJs or Angular 2?

Comment: @SarathMohandas yes it did not work.

Comment: @NavnathJadhav it is Angular 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am getting it right, you want to show 'X' when it's un-checked. In that case, below CSS will be helpful:

```css
mat-checkbox.cross {
  .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='24px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24px' fill='%23ff4081'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h24v24H0V0z' fill='none'/%3E%3Cpath d='M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12 19 6.41z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

You will need to use class with `<mat-checkbox>`:

```html
<mat-checkbox class="cross">...</mat-checkbox>
```

I have also created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyykpy?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: Thank you so much for answer  but it works only in global css and it will apply to whole project. i just want to use it on one component view.

Comment: You can simply handle it through a class. Updated the answer. Just use `class="cross"` wherever you want cross.

Comment: Thank you That's Exactly what i didi i created simple class and it works.